# Why bigger dimension device has less screen.width compared to some smaller dimension device?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, screen, pixel

During testing, I found out that few very large dimension device Oppo (5.5") has `screen.width`equals to `360px`where as lower dimension device like iPhone 7 has `screen.width` equals to `375px`.

How do I understand the nuances and measure the device width effectively?

Answer (score 0):

px means pixel i.e. number of illuminated spots. This is only dependant on the screen resolution, not the width as a unit of length.

Answer (score 0):

If you want the effective window width you can try this.

```js
console.log($(window).width()); // returns width of browser viewport
console.log($(window).height()); // returns height of browser viewport
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

For more details read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3437825/7499069)